# Generate an array (of variable size) only from parameters

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm pretty new to Verilog and I am trying to generate an array from different parameters.

What I want to do is assemble lists defined in parameters, separate them with a separator (3'b000). I have X slaves and each slaves got Y addresses. The hard point is that I do not know how much addresses there will be per slaves. It is something like that that I want (with the generatedReg automatically generated from parameters):

```
parameter numberOfSlaves=3;
parameter numberofAddr=5;
parameter [1:0] listAddrForSlave1=[3'bxxx, 3'bxxx]
parameter [0:0] listAddrForSlave2=[3'bxxx]
parameter [1:0] listAddrForSlave3=[3'bxxx, 3'bxxx]
reg [numberofSlaves+numberofAddr-1:0] generatedReg=[3'bxxx, 3'bxxx, 3'b000, 3'bxxx, 3'b000, 3'bxxx, 3'bxxx, 3'b000]
```

So in the parameters, I could also have listAddrForSlave4 and it should be appended to the generatedReg (with the same code). What I want is to generate an array without having the user put the separator.
How do I do that please? Do you have any track of reflexion for me?

I hope it is more clear with this edit.

Thanks and have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Your `listAddrForSlave...` variables are irregular (have different widths). As such, it is impossible to do in verilog. For regular vars, you can use a parameter array and parameterized modules. Size of the array could be defined at instantiation time. Something like the following might help you.

```
module ctrl #(int numberOfSlaves = 1, int numberOfAddr=1)();
   parameter [1:0] listAddrForSlave[numberOfSlaves] = '{default: 3'bxxx}; //initialize all elements of an array with a default value.
   reg [numberOfSlaves+numberOfAddr-1:0] generatedReg; // it will be 'x' by default.
   //...
endmodule
```

The above module can be instantiated with different parameters.

```
module top();
  ctrl ctrl1(); // instantiation with default values
  ctrl #(.numberOfSlaves(3)) ctl1(); // instantiation with 3 slaves (and one address)
  //...
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answered, I will have some work to do from that. So if I use foreach loops in an initial block to put values in generatedReg (via the parameters defined), will the synthetisis be the same as if I affected directly generatedReg? Thanks again

Comment: It depends on synthesis target. The best generic way is to provide a regular reset feature in your code and avoid initial blocks, except in test benches.